# The document picker ... failed to launch

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, document-provider

I have created my own DocumentPickerExtensionViewController and want to be able to open it up in the Excel app on iOS.
In the office app I press Open -> ... More -> Locations and choose my extensions name. 
But after about two seconds of loading a dialog pops up saying "The document picker ... failed to launch (0)".

I can't find anything about this error when Googling. Does anyone know what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I tried creating a new test app and document provider with Xcode which worked out of the box. I realised that Xcode was creating a Document Provider project as well as a File Provider project and what I was missing in my Xamarin project was the File Provider since I won't be using iCloud.
After adding a File Provider project I no longer got an error message.